# VB.NET Dataset update

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset, dataadapter

I'm new to vb.net and having quite a challenge with updating a field in a table using the For...Next construct on a data set.  Sample code below - can anyone tell me what I'm missing?  I know this particular example could be accomplished with a simple SQL update statement, but the actual use for what this code will become requires stepping through each record in the dataset. The example below is just a simple one to let me get the procedure down.  Note that this runs without an exception, but just doesn't change the data in the table.

Help! :)

---

```
    Dim objConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DALLAS\;Initial Catalog=Adaptive;Integrated Security=True")

    Dim selectCMD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from dwbprocref", objConn)
    selectCMD.CommandTimeout = 30

    Dim custDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
    custDA.SelectCommand = selectCMD

    Dim custCB As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(custDA)
    custCB.QuotePrefix = "["
    custCB.QuoteSuffix = "]"


    Dim dRow As DataRow
    Dim dTable As DataTable

    objConn.Open()

    Dim custDS As DataSet = New DataSet
    custDA.Fill(custDS, "dwbprocref")

    For Each dRow In custDS.Tables(0).Rows
        If dRow.Item("pr_format") = "MDV" Then
            dRow.Item("pr_tester") = "X"
        End If
        custDS.AcceptChanges()
    Next
    custDA.Update(custDS, "dwbprocref")

    objConn.Close()
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `AcceptChanges`. This marks all of the rows as being unmodified, so they are never updated in the database. Remove this call and you should be good.